# How to get inline-block elements to print straight across?

Tags: html, css

I have the following block of code:

```
<div class="1">
  Foo<br>1
</div>
<div class="2">
  Bar<br>2
</div>
```

Both `.1` and `.2` are set to `position:relative;display:inline-block`. However, they display like this:

```
     Bar
Foo  2
1
```

Apparently, class `.2` is vertically positioned where it naturally would be, but the first line of class `.1` starts at the level of the second line of `.2`, so the whole div is pushed down. This seems strange to me, because `.2` comes after `.1`, so I would expect `.2` to be positioned based on where `.1` is, not the other way around. This pattern continues as I add more divs before `.1`. How can I get them to display straight across, like this?

```
Foo Bar
1   2
```

Comment: Could you please create a demo fiddle. With information provided, I am unable to simulate the issue.

Comment: What on earth? In this fiddle, they aren't even displaying next to each other. Do you know why that could be? http://jsfiddle.net/uxfzmqu0/

Comment: Are you using Less/SASS for CSS? With pure CSS you cannot nest selectors like in the fiddle.

Comment: Oh that's right! But un-nesting it doesn't make it work either. http://jsfiddle.net/uxfzmqu0/1/

Comment: Class names typically should not start with a number (atleast till before HTML5) and that is why it wasn't working in fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the others said, `1` and `2` won't work for class names; I've changed them to `a` and `b` respectively. And they're also correct that your CSS is nested but you didn't select SCSS for your fiddle so that's invalid CSS. Fix those two things and it works:

```css
.wrapper { position: relative; display: inline-block; }
.a, .b { position: relative; display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">
    Foo<br>1
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    Bar<br>2
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, please disregard the suggestions about using tables and floats. They aren't wrong, but they won't specifically fix what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the elements to be aligned as shown in your example, you can use float or inline-block.

```css
.class1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
.class2 {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">Foo
    <br />1</div>
<div class="class1">Bar
    <br />2</div>
<hr />
<div class="class2">Foo
    <br />1</div>
<div class="class2">Bar
    <br />2</div>
```

Note that you are using invalid classnames, see spec [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters).  In short, class names must begin with an underscore (_), a hyphen (-), or a letter(a–z), followed by any number of hyphens, underscores, letters, or numbers. Furthermore, if the first character is a hyphen, the second character must be a letter or underscore and the name must be at least 2 characters long.  Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code.